# How to append a C# formatted html

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a button that append's the same layout of html but I have a problem taking the select values with it. My html is:

```
<div id="degreePlusSign">Button</div>
<div class="padding">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
        <label for="prefix" class="sr-only">Degrees</label>
        <select class="form-control marginBottom15">
        @{
            foreach (var degree in ViewBag.NewDegrees)
            {               
            <option value="@degree.DegreeID" selected>@degree.DegreeName</option>
            }
          }
         </select>
         <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#degreePlusSign').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.padding').append('<div class="padding mBottom"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12"><select class="form-control marginBottom15">@{foreach (var degree in ViewBag.NewDegrees){<option value="@degree.DegreeID" selected>@degree.DegreeName</option>}}</select><span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span></div><div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12"><input class="form-control" placeholder="Major/Area of Study" type="text" /></div></div>');
});
```

Basically it recreates the html, but my problem is I'm using a foreach loop to bring in the values from the backend and it will only work with the inital container, not the duplicated containers afterwards. How do I keep the values on every duplication with the append jquery?

Comment: Hi, by declaring that all the `option` are `selected`, the actually selected value, it would be the last option in the select list. Is that you are looking for?

Comment: No, currently the inital html contains the values inside the select tag. What I'm doing is if they want to add more, the click the button to replicate the html. But the select values will be empty since the values aren't being brought in on the duplication. How do I do that?

Comment: What values do you want it to be populated with?

Comment: with the same values that it pulls in ( ViewBag.NewDegrees )

Comment: I updated with the model inside the append as to what I hope it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got two options:

1. Spit options values (formatted) from C# and keep in a JS variable:

```
    {
       var opts=new StringBuilder();
       var sel="selected";
       foreach(var d in ViewBag.NewDegrees)
       {
           opts.Append($"{d.DegreeName}");
           sel="";
       }
    }
```

Then somewhere down store it into a js variable:

```
var optsList="@(opts)";
```

Now you can use append new HTML as:

```
$('#degreePlusSign').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.padding').append('<div class="padding mBottom"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12"><select class="form-control marginBottom15">'+

optsList/*THIS IS THE VALUE WE STORED FROM C# CODE*/

+'</select><span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span></div><div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12"><input class="form-control" placeholder="Major/Area of Study" type="text" /></div></div>');
});
```

2. Clone the generated `select` element and use that:

```
$('#degreePlusSign').on('click', function () {
    /*CLONE EXISTING SELECT ELEMENT. YOU MAY WANT TO PUT AN ID FOR SELECTION*/
    var cl=$("select.form-control.marginBottom15").clone();

    var d = $("").addClass("padding mBottom")
              append("").addClass("fa fa-times-circle fa-2x").attr("aria-hidden",'true');

    /*APPEND CLONED SELECT TO INNER DIV*/
    d.append("").addClass("col-md-5 col-xs-12").append(cl);
    d.append(cl);

    d.append("").addClass(glyphicon form-control-feedback");
    d.append("").addClass("col-md-7 col-xs-12").append("").addClass("form-control")
    .attr("placeholder","Major/Area of Study").attr("type","text");

    $(this).closest(".padding").append(d);    
});`
```

Hope you will be able fix any jQuery mess. I haven't used it since long.

Comment: I figured it out right as you did, but I'll give you credit for the work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.clone was what I was looking for. $('.padding').clone().append('.padding');